# Regexp for a valid user-agent

Tags: language-agnostic, http-headers

I'm trying to write a regexp that validates if a user-agent given by a user is valid.

I've found http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html section "14.43 User-Agent":

> **14.43 User-Agent**
>
> The User-Agent request-header field contains information about the user agent originating the request. This is for statistical purposes, the tracing of protocol violations, and automated recognition of user agents for the sake of tailoring responses to avoid particular user agent limitations. User agents SHOULD include this field with requests. The field can contain multiple product tokens (section 3.8) and comments identifying the agent and any subproducts which form a significant part of the user agent. By convention, the product tokens are listed in order of their significance for identifying the application.
>
> ```
>   User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>   User-Agent: CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3
> ```

but I'm not really sure what does it mean `1*`. Could anybody explain it or write the regexp?

Thanks!

Comment: In [ABNF](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.1), `1*` means one or more repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [notation at the start of the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html), you can see that `N*M rule` means `N` to `M` repetitions of `rule`. `N` is optional, and defaults to zero. `M` is optional, and defaults to infinity. In normal regular expressions, this translates to: `rule{N,M}`

In your case, `1*` means *one or more repetitions*. In normal regular expressions, you can use the postfix `+` operator: `rule+`